# SQL Server table index columns order

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, query-performance

Is there any difference when I create a table index for more columns if I use the columns in different order?

Exactly is difference between `ID, isValid, Created` and `ID, Created, isValid` indices?

And is there any difference in querying order?

```
where ID = 123 
  and isValid = 1 
  and Created < getdate()
```

vs.

```
where ID = 123 
  and Created < getdate() 
  and isValid = 1
```

Column types: ID *[int]*, isValid *[bit]*, Created *[datetime]*)

Comment: You would want `ID, isValid , Created` there. So seek on the first two columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Exactly is difference between `ID, isValid, Created` and `ID, Created, isValid` indices?

<strike>If you always use **all three** columns in your `WHERE` clause - there's no difference.</strike>
(*as Martin Smith points out in his comment - since of the criteria is not an equality check, the sequence of the columns in the index **does** matter*)

However: an index can only ever used if the n left-most columns (here: n between 1 and 3) are used.

So if you have a query that might only use `ID` and `isValid` for querying, then the first index *can* be used - but the second one will *never* be used for sure.

And if you have queries that use `ID` and `Created` as their `WHERE` parameters, then your second index *might* be used, but the first one can never be used.

Comment: It does make a difference here as they are not all equality predicates.

Comment: @MartinSmith: it does? Can you explain further (or point to an explanation)? So which of the two indexes would be preferable here - the one with the inequality column `Created` at the end?

Comment: Yes. You'd want created at the end to maximise efficiency. If it was at the beginning you'd just get a range seek on `< GetDate` and scan a load of rows that don't necessarily match the other two predicates. If at the end you can do an equality seek on those then just do the range seek on matching rows.

Comment: So if you had all three comparison with an **equality** - then my statement of *there's no difference* would be correct?

Answer (score 1):

`AND` is commutative, so the order of ANDed expressions in `WHERE` doesn't matter.
Order of columns in an index *does* matter, it should match your queries.

If `ID` is your table's clustered primary key and your queries ask for specific `ID`, don't bother creating an index. That would be like giving an index to a book saying "page 123 is on page 123" etc.

Answer (score 1):

The order in the query makes no difference. The order in the index makes a difference. I'm not sure how good this will look in text but here goes:

```
where ID = 123 and isValid = 1 and Created < Date 'Jan 3'
```

Here are a couple of possible indexes:

```
ID   IsValid Created
===  ======= =========
122  0       Jan 4
122  0       Jan 3
...  ...     ...
123  0       Jan 4
123  0       Jan 3
123  0       Jan 2
123  0       Jan 1
123  1       Jan 4
123  1       Jan 3
123  1       Jan 2 <-- Your data is here...
123  1       Jan 1 <-- ... and here
...  ...     ...

ID   Created IsValid
===  ======= ========
122  Jan 4   0
122  Jan 4   1
...  ...     ...
123  Jan 4   0
123  Jan 4   1
123  Jan 3   0
123  Jan 3   1
123  Jan 2   0
123  Jan 2   1     <-- Your data is here...
123  Jan 1   0
123  Jan 1   1     <-- ... and here
...  ...     ...
```

As you can probably tell, creating an index(IsValid, Created, ID) or any other order, will separate your data even more. In general, you want to design the indexes to make your data as "clumpy" as possible for the queries executed most often.